# How do I save a variable in flutter and make it accessible to all my files?

Tags: flutter, dart

I basically get a password and 6 digit code from the user and I want to save this to a variable. I know it is already saved as "controller.text" and "code" but once I go to the next screen I will not be able to access them. I tried using a class and passing these two parameters there but that means I have to instantiate it every time I want to get the password/code and I won't be able to do this since I won't have anything to pass through. Can someone help or suggest a different way of doing this?

```
Container(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Submit"),
              onPressed: () async {
                 currentCollection.createCollection(controller.text, code);
                },
            ),
          ),
```

```
class Collection{

  static  String password;
  static  int code;
  Collection(password,code);
  static final  String collectionName = password;
  static final int passcode = code;

  getPassword()
  {
  return password;
  }
  getCode()
  {
  return code;
  }



}
```

Comment: Did you try creating a singleton? You may also look into Provider or InheritedModel to pass data.

Comment: declare a static variable in the class and then you can access the variable from anywhere without creating the instance of the class, otherwise if you want to pass data down the widget tree @ShubhamGupta explain in the above comment use bloc, redux, provider there are various state management technique.

Comment: @AtulChaudhary I posted above what you said. Like that? I can not access it from other files. Could you fix if it is not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple, outside of all your classes/widgets/functions
You create variable like

```dart
var sharedPass;
```

and change it's value when you need to, like

```dart
Container(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Submit"),
              onPressed: () async {
                 sharedPass = controller.text;
                 currentCollection.createCollection(controller.text, code);
                },
            ),
          ),
```

now you can use it's value anywhere, like

```
Text(sharedPass)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the variables in Shared Preferences (`shared_preferences`) or Secure Storage (`flutter_secure_storage`). Then you can retrieve them from any page/file.

Secure Storage is appropriate if you want to store passwords and the like.

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
```

To save the variables:

```
final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
await storage.write(key: 'password', value: password);
await storage.write(key: 'code', value: code);
```

To read the variables:

```
final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
password = (await storage.read(key: 'password')) ?? '';
code = (await storage.read(key: 'code')) ?? '';
```